# Why can I not establish access to my Facebook app?

Tags: php, facebook

I am following the instructions on [this page](http://tips4php.net/2010/12/automatic-post-to-facebook-from-php-script/) to create a PHP script which will (hopefully) allow me to post to Facebook from my web site.

All I really want to establish is the ability to enter text and a link into a form on my web site and have it be posted to a Facebook wall.

My understanding is that I need to validate a Facebook app in order to do this, which is what brought me to the above web page.

I have followed their instructions dutifully, and by now I have been through it many times, checking to make sure I have followed their steps accurately.

However, when it gets to the part where I run fb_access.php from my web site, I get absolutely no response from Facebook.

I notice that the screen shot examples on the page I am using are not what I am seeing in the Facebook interface. The tutorial is from December 2010, which I would hope is recent enough, but perhaps things have changed...?

How do I get Facebook to respond to my PHP script?

```
<?
require_once 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "<my App ID";
$app_secret = "<my App Secret>";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $app_id,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'cookie' => true
));

if(is_null($facebook->getUser()))
{
 header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos'))}");
 exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Go to facebook.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Can I get the mods to migrate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Facebook PHP SDK demo script here:

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

Once you have this script running - you can then begin to request calls, such as post to wall. If the call is successful, FB will prompt you with a Request for Permission.

Comment: That worked better than the script I was working with... though still not flying. Short story: I eventually saw this error: API Error Code: 191 API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri. However, I've set my URL in "App->Basic Settings->App Domain". Is there another domain setting?

Comment: FB restricts the "redirect_uri" and "next" param to the domain set in that App Domain field - if working on a development url, e.g. http://localhost - make sure App Domain is localhost